# How to store tuples in a pandas dataframe cell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv import of datas store in such fashion

```
username;groups
alice;(admin,user)
bob;(user)
```

I want to do some data analysis on it and import them to a pandas dataframe so that the first column is stored as a string and the second as a tuple.

I tried `mydataframe = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')` then convert the groups column with astype method `mydataframe['groups'].astype('tuple')` but it won't work.

How to store other objects than strings/ints/floats in dataframes?
Thanks.

Comment: The potential problem is that converting a string like `"(admin,user)"` directly to a tuple would result in every single character becoming an element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but try

```
mydataframe['groups'].apply(lambda text: tuple(text[1:-1].split(',')))
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine thanks, though the ```tuple(text[1;-1]``` must be changed for ```tuple(text[0;-1]``` otherwise the first character is droped

Comment: @Odyseus_v4 The first character *should* be dropped: it's an opening parenthesis, `(`.

Comment: Oh alright, I then modified the csv to drop the parenthesis in there.